# Change off screen view color when animating view off screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview adapter, and when you click on an item in the list, it opens it up to a full screen activity. I have added a 'swipe to dismiss' functionality within the app. When the user swipes from the left side of the screen, and starts dragging, I set the X position of the top layout in the full screen activity to be the X position of the user's finger. I want to know how to change the color of the gap between the edge of the activity and the edge of the device. It is just white now, but I want it to be transparent to be able to see the adapter below the activity. I have tried setting the background color of the top layout in the full screen activity to be transparent. Here is a crude image describing what I want to achieve.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uRCV.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add this to your theme in your styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

But I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel and use a library for this if you can:
https://github.com/r0adkll/Slidr

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer! You linked me to a Javascript library though? So I don't think that will be any help.

Comment: @joebro Sorry they had the same name :/ Fixed